# Prove that $n^2 + 2^n$ is composite if $n\not\equiv3\pmod{6}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factoring, perfect-powers

> If $n>1$ is an integer not of the form $6k+3$, Prove that $n^2 + 2^n$ is composite.

Any idea of how to think about this problem? I have been thinking about it a lot and yet I was not able to come up with anything.

Comment: That it told you not to consider the case of $n=6k+3$, perhaps you can break it down into cases.  There are six cases to consider overall, one of which you are told to ignore, and three of which are immediate.  So, try thinking about what happens if $n=6k+1$ or $n=6k+5$.

Comment: Well if $n$ is even, it is clearly divisible by 2. I suspect after looking at values out to 21 that in the odd cases it is divisible by 3...

Comment: @jmoravitz i was thinking about the cases but i did not know which cases to consider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $n$ is even then $n^2+2^n$ is even, and if $n\equiv\pm1\pmod{6}$ then $n^2+2^n\equiv1+2\equiv0\pmod3$.

Comment: I am having a little difficult understanding how did you reduce to modular to 3

Comment: If you know Euler's theorem you can use that $\varphi(3)=2$. Otherwise, you can use some simple calculations to show that $n^2\equiv1\pmod3$ because $n\not\equiv0\pmod3$, and $2^n\equiv2\pmod3$ because $n\equiv1\pmod2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, the proof is trivial. Let $n=2m$, then $n^2+2^n=4m^2+4^m$ which is divisible by 4.

If $n$ is odd, consider $n=6k+1$.

When $k=1, n^2+2^n=177$

When $k=2, n^2+2^n=8361$

When $k=3, n^2+2^n=52469$

We wish to show that for all $k>0$, $(6k+1)^2+2^{6k+1} \equiv 0\pmod 3$. Let $a_k=(6k+1)^2+2^{6k+1}$. Assume the case $n=k$ is true. When $n=k+1$
$$a_{k+1}=(6(k+1)+1)^2+2^{6(k+1)+1}=(6k+1)^2+36+12(6k+1)+64(2^{6k+1})\equiv (6k+1)^2+2^{6k+1}=a_k$$

Thus, this means $$a_k\equiv a_{k-1} \equiv a_{k-2}\equiv...\equiv a_1\equiv 0\pmod 3$$
Our inductive proof is complete.

Comment: The proof for $n=6k-1$ is similar.